# Can I instantiate a type based on a value in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5

I have 2 classes both inherit from the same interface.
i want sometimes to run the website using one class and sometimes with another one.
Want to decide which one to use based on a configuration value.
Can i use web.config to decide which class to create the current instance from?

Comment: question title and question don't quite match up....

Comment: ...do you want to explicitly load an assembly containing a specfic type, or simply be able to change a concrete type at runtime?

Comment: perhaps, "Can I instantiate a type based on a value in web.config?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Create a factory method that returns an object of type `IMyInterface`. Pass in the config value as a parameter to determine which concrete object to create.

```
IMyInterface FactoryMethod(string configValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you can. Of interest to you is the field `AssemblyQualifiedName` of `Type`. So get your type and do:

```
myObj.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName
```

And write the result of this into your config:

```
<add key="TypeName" Value="...." />
```

Then, you'll need to consider what constructors it has, and it can be loaded like so:

```
Type.GetType("...").GetConstructor(...).Invoke(...);
```

Comment: No worries Mitch, I'm guessing it was the OP given his comment to you :)

Comment: voting up, as it could of been the right answer depending how the original question was interpreted

Comment: wasn't me as well, i didn't try your solution yet, just found Mitch answer simple and understood very fast, also will try yours

Comment: Amr: They're both kind of the same anyway. Mitch's is probably a better way to abstract out the creation of the types (I haven't told you how to do that in mine), but either way you may be creating the types reflectively, or not, and for a reflective-create you can use the info I've provided to help figure out how. The answer you have accepted is probably the most appropriate. All good.